# Should I use hypophoras at the beginning of every paragraphs?

Tags: academic-writing

> [Hypophora](http://literarydevices.net/hypophora/) is a figure of speech in which a writer raises a question and then immediately provides an answer to that question.

I am about to write a Statement of Purpose. In the SOP, I need to answer [some questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1529/choosing-research-ideas-to-include-in-a-statement-of-purpose/):

- What have you already done?
- What are you working on now?
- What might you want to work on in the future?
- How does my department fit your research goals?

Each paragraph, of course, will be an answer for each question. Instead of writing those paragraphs normally, I would like to start them with the questions they will answer for. In short, I will use hypophoras to start those paragraphs. However, I'm afraid that using them a lot will be counterproductive. Should I use hypophoras at the beginning of every paragraphs?

Answer (score 2):

If these questions are explicitly given to you as worded, I think you can make them into section headers, and organize your responses under them.

The hypophora as you reference it describes situations where the writer is raising a question in order to discuss it, not answering a question which someone else has posed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I can see your opinion is conflict with Kristina Adams, I have opened [this question](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/16085/when-should-headers-be-used-in-writing) to learn deeper. I hope you will join there.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a style guide for what you're writing? That should give you advice on using things like headers.

I would advise against using headers or hypophoras if you can - writing is much more eloquent if you can answer the questions without labelling them. For example:

> 'I have written a series of novels about...'
>
> 'I am now working on a new novel about...'
>
> 'These projects will lead me towards...'
>
> 'I feel this course will be of benefit to me because...'

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I can see your opinion is conflict with Lauren Ipsum, I have opened [this question](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/16085/when-should-headers-be-used-in-writing) to learn deeper. I hope you will join there.

Comment: Also, I only have *content guide* for this, not *writing guide*