# When should headers be used in writing?

Tags: style, headlines

When I ask the [Should I use hypophoras at the beginning of every paragraphs?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/16075/should-i-use-hypophoras-at-the-beginning-of-every-paragraphs/16076#16076) question, Lauren Ipsum suggests me to organize things with headers while Kristina Adams advises me to avoid headers in order to make my writing more eloquent. I see both opinions can be right at the same time. I think these advices work in different contexts. When should we use headers in writing?

---

After Kristina answers, I think that I can use hypophoras as the first sentences of every paragraphs like "soft"-headers. You don't recognize it after reading some of them. Does this method useful?

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the piece and on what it's for. Most people will highly advise using headers for blog posts, for instance, because search engines LOVE them and they're useful for skim-readers. Generally you wouldn't use headers in a novel, short story or poem, but that's not to say that you can't or that it hasn't been done. When it comes to academic writing, it can also depend on the paper and who you're writing it for. Some markers will find headers useful because it helps them to go back and check things over, but it can interrupt the flow and be jarring also.

It really depends on the audience.

Comment: So back to the previous question, my intention is making a soft header. You don't realize it until you are actually read it. Is this approach good enough?